# nginx file location search in subdirectories

Tags: linux, regex, nginx

I have a problem with nginx configuration, and i don't know that is it possible or not, to solve my problem.

I have a lot of photos which i need to server. The problem is, all these images ar in the same directory. The 'solution' is to re-directroy the images, for example:
Now i have 11.png, 12.png, 13.png, 22.png.
What i want is, the images with napi 1x.png it will be in directory 1, so the location is 1/11.png, 1/12.png, ...
The problem is, how can i solve this in nginx config? If i make a request to example.com/11.png the nginx first look in the root directory and the next one is 1/11.png. I thought that the try_files is a good solution but i need to automate to search the filename first letter and check in that directory.

I tried mapping with regex, the regex is: `^.*data\/product\/\b(\w)`

But i stuck with that problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example:

```
location ~ ^(/images/)(\w)(\w*\.\w+)$ {
    try_files $uri $1$2/$2$3 =404;
}
```

For a requested URL of `/images/1234.png`, the [regular expression location](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) will make the following three captures:

```
$1 = /images/
$2 = 1
$3 = 234.png
```

The `try_files` statement will first try `/path/to/root/images/1234.png` and then `/path/to/root/images/1/1234.png`.

Comment: Wow, works fine, thank you very much! But i find a problem with long file names. Do you have any idea? For example: one_two_three_four.jpg, this image i can't access under the o directory.

Comment: `\w` matches the ASCII characters `A-Za-z0-9_`. Double check that your long filenames do not contain other characters - otherwise you will need to adjust the regular expression.

Comment: Thank you very much your help! The final regex is: `^(/images/)([A-Za-z0-9_\-!~$.])([A-Za-z0-9_\-!~$.]*\.[A-Za-z0-9_\-!~$.]+)$`